# i think theres something wrong with this array but i dont know what?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d",& n );
    int array[n];
    scanf("\n%d",array );
    int i;
    for( i=0;i<=n;i++)
    if(array[i]>array[i-1]&&array[i]>array[i+1]){
        printf("\n%d",array[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The input is both the size and the elements of the array, the program should print the elements that are larger from its neighbors (the elements in right and left side of it)

input: 5 (size of the array)
2 4 3 2 1 (the elements of the array)

output: 4 (is larger from 2 and 3)

Comment: At least specify what's the current behavior of the program. // Although you should think about it a little carefully, and remember that out-of-bound array access is undefined behavior.

Comment: Your program does out-of-range access.

Comment: You only scanf one item so why the array?

Comment: @Saba zare You can not read a whole array using such call of scanf scanf("\n%d",array );. This scanf reads a value only for the first element of the array. Also if an array has n elements then the valid range of indices is [0, n)

Comment: One major problem is that you go out of bounds in *each* direction of the array: You use `-1` as index as well as `n` and `n + 1`.

Comment: And you probably need to go through your text-book or class-notes or tutorials to see how they read into an array, because you only read a single element into `array[0]`.

Comment: `scanf("\n%d",array );` but why?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to do this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  int i, n;
  printf("Enter length of array : ");
  scanf("%d", & n);

  int array[n];

  //getting values for array
  printf("Enter elements of array : \n");
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("array[%d] => ", i);
    scanf("%d", & array[i]);

  }
  printf("Output : ");
  for (i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) {
    if (array[i] > array[i - 1] && array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
      printf("%d\t", array[i]);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

One thing to note here is you can use malloc(), realloc() for dynamic allocation.
I was thinking not to code the answer but it seems you're new to C.
So first start learning basics

Comment: please consider answer accepted if this helped